# Confirmation regarding nucleophilic addition of Grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

> $\ce{A ->[(i)EtMgCl][(ii)H2O] Et3C-OH}$
>
> A can be:
>
> a) $\ce{COCl2}$
>
> b) $\ce{EtCOOEt}$
>
> c) $\ce{Et2CO}$
>
> d) $\ce{All}$

The answer should be (d) according to me, but is marked as (a) in the answer key.

Option (c) obviously gives the required product, as does (b). I derived this scheme for (a)-

$$\ce{2COCl2 + 2EtMgCl -> Et2CO + 2MgCl2}$$
$$\ce{Et2CO + EtMgCl -> Et3C-OMgCl ->[H2O] Et3C-OH + Mg(OH)Cl}$$

Could one please confirm if the above reaction scheme is correct? I personally could not find any flaw in it.

Comment: Seems like a goof up by the book: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/grignard-reaction.shtm

Comment: I agree, certainly b and c are viable answers

Comment: I dont see how this is related to the 'synthesis' of Grignard reagent. Well if we were impractically *too* critical about the fact that the reagents aren't provided in excess, then also the answer should have been (c) and not (a). So I agree too, unless someone comes to enlighten us

Answer (score 2):

The answer is all of them, thus (d).  In the case of $\ce{COCl2}$ (a), the Grignard reagent displaces both chloride ions in successive nucleophilic substitutions, forming diethyl ketone; then the reaction continues as it would for a typical ketone.

The displacement if a chloride ion in the case of an acyl chloride is described [here](https://www.chemistryscl.com/reactions/organic/CH3MgBr+CH3COCl/index.php).  Reaction with $\ce{COCl2}$ would simply involve two stages of this process.